# Expected identifier or '(' xcode error comming

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

There are two pages one for registration and other for login. username and password in login page should match with data in registration page. To do this i am using if-else statement for button that if data in registration page== login page username and password then go to next page on button click otherwise display error.

This is .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController2 : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>

@property(strong,nonatomic)NSString *dataString;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *inputTxt1;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *inputTxt2;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblOutput;

- (IBAction)btnAction:(id)sender;

@end
```

this is .m file

```
#import "ViewController2.h"

@interface ViewController2 ()
{
    int x;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController2

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.title=@"Login Id Page";

    NSLog(@"Data String is %@",self.dataString);

    _inputTxt1.delegate=self;

    _inputTxt2.delegate=self;

    _inputTxt1.returnKeyType=UIReturnKeyNext;

    _inputTxt2.returnKeyType=UIReturnKeyDone;

    if (_inputTxt1.text == self.dataString){
        x=1;
    }
    else{
        x=0;
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}


-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == self.inputTxt1) {

        [self.inputTxt2 becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else if (textField == self.inputTxt2)
    {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
    }
    return YES;
}

//error is comming right here at if statement:-

if (x==1)
{
    - (IBAction)btnAction:(id)sender {
        //navigation to next page
    }
}

else
{
    _lblOutput.text = @"wrong username or password";
}
@end
```

Comment: You cannot conditionally define methods. `- (IBAction)btnAction:` must be outside of the `if` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do like

//error is comming right here at if statement:-

```
if (x==1)
{
   [self performseguewithIdentifier:@"xxxx"];
}

else
{
_lblOutput.text = @"wrong username or password";
  }
```

**choice-2**

```
if (x==1)
{
  [self btnAction:nil];
}

else
{
_lblOutput.text = @"wrong username or password";
  }
```

cal method like

```
- (IBAction)btnAction:(id)sender {
    //navigation to next page
   [self performseguewithIdentifier:@"xxxx"];
  // or do ur stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first you define

```
    - (IBAction)btnAction:(id)sender 
    {
     //navigation to next page
    }
```

then call it

```
if (x==1)
{
    [self btnAction:nil];   //here
}
```